# Functional JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Okay I understand that in the forEach function the action parameter is acting as the print function and being called on each element in the array for the following Code Below:

```
    function forEach(array, action) {
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
             action(array[i]);
    }

    forEach(["Wampeter", "Foma", "Granfalloon"], print);
```

But in the next example a function definition is being passed in place of the action parameter for forEach as follows:

```
    function sum(numbers) {
      var total = 0;
      forEach(numbers, function (number) {
             total += number;
      });
     return total;
    }
   show(sum([1, 10, 100]));
```

Which I am lost at. This code some how prints out the sum of a given array but I can not explain how it does it or how it works.
Question 1: How or when is number given a value since it is local and used to give total its final value?
Question 2: How is total += number acting on each element in the array.

Comment: What are you confused about? Read up on scoping in Javascript.

Comment: the second argument to `forEach` is a function object which is called on each element of the Array with the respective array element as an argument. the function object actually is a closure, meaning that it implicitly receives access to (part of) the environment at the definition location: in this case, it's the `total` variable which can therefore be used as an accumulator to compute the aggregate `sum` making it available to the caller without explicit handshake.

Answer (score 1):

The argument `number` is passed into the anonymous function which is called for each element in the array.  The `number` argument contains the value of the current array element.  The value is added to the global variable `total` during each iteration, which creates the sum of all the array values.  The function then returns `total`.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a function inside of another function is called a closure.  The inner function has full access to the local variables defined in the outer function.

So when the function used as `action` in the `forEach()` call does `total += number`, this is adding `number` (the argument) to `total` (the local variable in `sum()`).  After the `forEach()` call has completed each number from `numbers` will have been added to `total`, and `total` is returned.

Comment: Awesome i get it now! I was looking over the fact that in this situation array[i] = number because thats the parameter that the function is acting on.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `numbers` as your first param for forEach, so it will go through each elements in that array and then you are doing `total += number;` which means `total = total + number;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout how forEach works at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Or implementing it helps a lot in understanding

```js
var each = function(array, func) {
  var aLength = array.length,
    retArr = [],
    i;
  for (i = 0; i < aLength; i++) {
    func(array[i], i, array);
  }
};

function sum(numbers) {
  var total = 0;
  each(numbers, function(number) {
    total += number;
  });
  return total;
}
console.log(sum([1, 10, 100]));
```

You should also checkout [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Using reduce for the same task looks as follows

```js
function sum(numbers) {
  return numbers.reduce(function(total, item){
    return total + item;
  });
}
console.log(sum([1, 10, 100]));
```

Or even without a wrapping function

```js
console.log([1, 10, 100].reduce(function(sum, num) {
  return sum + num;
}));
```